# While loop in SLURM script

Tags: python, cluster-computing, slurm

I am using a cluster to my computations for the first time, and as a result using a SLURM script for the first time.

I'm iterating the python code I'm using over a list of numbers. I did this before on my own machine with a simple while-loop in a bash script.

I thought this would translate fairly directly into the SLURM script. However, upon execution, only the first number of the list is read and executed, after which the execution stops. So, the rest of the ~200 numbers are ignored. 
Any ideas what could cause this?

Here is the SLURM script, for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

#SBATCH -o ./job.out.%j
#SBATCH -e ./job.err.%j
#SBATCH -D ./
#SBATCH -J NAME
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=40
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time=06:59:00

module load anaconda

while read IDX; do
    echo $PWD
    cd "model_"$IDX
    srun python ../mcmc.py 
    cd ".."
done <sample.txt
```

Comment: did you try to run it only with `echo $PWD, "model_"$IDX` ? Maybe  it works but `mcmc.py` has problem, or folder is incorrect.

Comment: Yes I tried that, and it runs as expected... so you're quite correct that the loop itself works. 
mcmc.py doesn't give me an error however (and I've run it plenty of times on a normal machine)
So could the cluster have a problem with repeated sruns in a loop somehow?!!
Thanks!

Comment: I never used SLURM. Maybe try with simple script - only with `print()` - to check if it will works. Script can be run with different privilages and not have access to folders, or it can returns value which system treads as error code (in python command `exit(value)`). Or maybe script should save info in file/log so you could see if it worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If "model_$IDX" does not exist, then the following `cd ..` will break the following iterations.

a simple fix for that is

```
while read IDX; do
    echo $PWD
    if cd "model_"$IDX; then
        srun python ../mcmc.py 
        cd ".."
    fi
done <sample.txt
```

If `IDX` is a positive integer and there are no dependencies between the runs, a more SLURM'ish way is to use [Job Array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html) (as long as your system limits allow you to submit job arrays that are big enough for your need)

your job script would be

```
#!/bin/bash -l

#SBATCH -o ./job.out.%j
#SBATCH -e ./job.err.%j
#SBATCH -D ./
#SBATCH -J NAME
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=40
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --time=06:59:00

module load anaconda

echo $PWD
cd "model_"$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
srun python ../mcmc.py
```

then use an external scripts that parse sample.txt, and create a string of comma separated indexes and

```
sbatch --array=<comma separated list of indexes> <slurm script>
```